# ClearQuest Api not Sorting with Specific Fields

Tags: c#, sorting, ole, clearquest

For some reason when I try to sort by any field that isn't `"total_est_hrs"`, or `"id"`, I get a null referenced exception. This is the code I am using to get queries:

```
Session cqSession = new Session();
cqSession.UserLogon("user", "password", "db", 2, "set");
IOAdQueryDef queryDef = (cqSession.BuildQuery("Defect"));

queryDef.BuildField("id");
queryDef.BuildField("total_est_hrs");
queryDef.BuildField("severity");

IOAdQueryFieldDefs fieldDefs = queryDef.QueryFieldDefs;

IOAdQueryFieldDef sortField = fieldDefs.item("severity");
sortField.SortType = 1;
sortField.SortOrder = 1;

IOAdQueryFilterNode rootNode = queryDef.BuildFilterOperator(AND);
rootNode.BuildFilter("submit_date", GREATER_THAN, "1/1/2014");

OAdResultset rs = (cqSession.BuildResultSet(queryDef));
rs.ExecuteAndCountRecords();
```

The error says there is a null reference exception on line 9, where I am attempting to set the `SortType`. The `GREATER_THAN` and `AND` constants refer to the sorting and comparison constants found on the ClearQuest Api refefence.

If someone could explain what is going on, that would be great.

Comment: Looks like the `severity` field isn't part of the `QueryDieldDefs` collection so doesn't get returned.

Comment: ok, so I guess I have to manually sort by the field names I need then, instead of relying on the ClearQeust api.